# Is 2020 really great?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash, wording, winter-bash-2020

Before you participate on Winter Bash the popup looks like this:

> [image: great year]

Is it ethically to name 2020 a great year despite global wide COVID-19 pandemic which took so many lives?

Comment: There's something to hate about every year. Besides, if you said it was "a terrible year", you'd offend all the people who had something *good* happen to them this past year, like graduating college, getting married, etc. You just can't win. Try not to read too much into throwaway marketing copy like this. It isn't a conspiracy.

Comment: Reopened. 2019 wasn't great because of a different reason.

Comment: Every year is going to be "not great" because of a different reason, but the underlying explanation for the marketing copy will be the same. Do we *really* need a bunch of short, pithy answers collected here, all saying the same thing, @Shadow?

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard The answer is the same. It's a boilerplate message.

Comment: @CodyGray *You earned Tinfoil Hat* for debunking a conspiracy.

Comment: @Xnero I disagree. It falls under "related", sure, but not same.

Comment: Think of it like *"The Great War"*

Comment: We deliberately changed the marketing copy elsewhere to not include this adjective. It is now removed here as well.

Comment: @CodyGray will the year of beginning of World War III be great? Or was the year of 1939 great?

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I don't know how you would allow a post to stay open where everyone posts short answers in why they thought 2020 was a great year when a similar discussion was had last year for a different reason and the answer was that it was the default text.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I was a history major. I can name events that render *any* year not great. That you can pick other years that you consider terrible only proves my point.

Comment: @YaakovEllis there's the sentence "a nice way to finish out another really amazing year" on https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/faq if you wanted to update that too

Comment: @kylejrp FAQ has been adjusted

Comment: @YaakovEllis Nice edit to the FAQ ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The words "a great" has been removed from the snowflake menu (showed up if you have not logged in yet), and been replaced with "the". The new text is: "Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of the year … with HATS!".

We deliberately did not include this adjective on the homepage of WB, missed this one instance.

> 2020, ugh
> maybe not so great it seems
> word has been removed

Comment: Can we propose replacement adjectives for WB2021?

Comment: You are welcome to propose anything that strikes your fancy.

Comment: I disagree with the adjective removal. For many and myself, 2020 was a great year.

Comment: I'm slightly confused ... If I was right, and removing the "great" was done deliberately on other places, why there are no upvotes on the question?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ The arguments in the other answers are perfectly valid arguments and likely why people are downvoting the question - they see this as a minor thing that doesn't need to be fixed. It just happened to be one that we had been trying to avoid, so it was fixed despite that. Sometimes having an answer like this will cause the question to increase in score - but who knows.

Comment: I'm still see "great" in popup (2020.12.18.38240)

Answer (score 6):

The users, moderators, and CMs of the Stack Exchange network pulled together and helped one another get through this year - helped people work, play, and stargaze.

This has been a good year for pulling together.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it was a great year... I think it was the greatest year I ever sat through: there seemed to be no end to it!

Answer (score 2):

It's up to each of us to make it great or not, yes I agree with you it was a difficult year specially for those who lost some one on family.

But you should always look at the sunny side, and you can make it great.

Answer (score 2):

## Every year is great actually!

Every year is a part of our lives.
I guess it doesn't matter whether was a year lucky or not. But I believe we should anyway be thankful for any year! Any year is great just because it *exists*! Let's be a little more optimistic! So common, have some fun! ;)

Comment: You have a point, but I've seen better years

Comment: @BlockofDiamond As I said `t doesn't matter whether was a year lucky or not`. So better years maybe was better but as great as any other ;D (sounds strange but true).

Answer (score 1):

Well, people die from all kinds of horrible things, COVID-19 is one of them, probably in the top.

However, we're still alive. We can still have fun, and humor is a great way to fight such nasty things.

2020 had, and still have, some great things for some people. Let's emrace those great things.

Happy bashing!

Comment: Well 1.65M for 7.7 billion is 2×10^-4(0.0002). But a drop in the ocean is 3.7×10^-26.
That's 5.4×10^21 drops in the ocean or a 270000 km^3 (cubic kilometers) drop. If cubic kilometers is hard to imagine pick one sport I will express the value in flooded [sport]field

Comment: In my country, more people have died from 9 months of COVID-19 than died in 4 years of WWII fighting. Your bland dismissal of its impact (which is by no means limited to death) is repulsive.

Comment: @jscs after reading your comment I re-read my answer, and you are right, the wording I chose was horrible, and didn't send the message I planned to send. Hope the edit makes it better. Sorry! (I wanted to edit right away and couldn't, then forgot about it until now)